# How to add each number from variable into an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, int

I have a variable like so:

```
$array = array();
$stock = 1500;
```

How can extract this number and add each number starting from 1 into `$array`.

For example:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 1500];
```

Comment: What should be your actual output?

Comment: I want the output to be an array of numbers like my example. So it counts to 1500

Comment: What have you tried? Showing bad code is better than no code.

Comment: This is very simple solution at least show some code what did you do to achieve this?

Comment: No need for loops. Have a look at [`range()`](http://php.net/range).

Comment: range() worked. thanks Qirel :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is [`range()`](http://php.net/range). No need for any loops - a simple one-liner is all you need!

```
$stock = 1500;
$array = range(1, $stock);
```

https://3v4l.org/QbHIB